# Crontab how to disable emails

Tags: cron

I want to disable email reports on some tasks which run frequently. I've gone through the following links

> https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84335/stop-cron-sending-mail-for-backup-script

> https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/disable-the-mail-alert-by-crontab-command/

They suggest adding `>/dev/null 2>&1` at the end of the command to disable emails.

This is my `crontab` entry :

```
* * * * * /bin/bash /home/ubuntu/startup/monitor-mosquitto.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

But I'm still receiving emails every time the script is run. In fact, not just once but I get like 8-15 mails every time it runs.

Am I doing anything wrong here ? BTW, I'm using crontab as root ( `sudo crontab -e` )

Answer (score 5):

See `man 5 crontab`:

> If MAILTO is defined but empty (MAILTO=""), no mail will be sent.

If memory serves, I have used that on the line itself, or preceding it:

```
MAILTO=""
* * * * * /bin/bash /home/ubuntu/startup/monitor-mosquitto.sh
```

Note that this will affect all lines that follow it so you may want to place it last, or renable `MAILTO`.

Also, strictly speaking, you should be able to work out what you did with shell redirection *in the shell itself*.  What you have looks correct so I am a little puzzled.  Maybe make sure to test it as `root` not as you.

Comment: note that in crontab default file, it is ```MAIL=""```, need to replace with `MAILTO=""` as mentionned by @dirk